# href + Slider (info)

Tags: php, html, css

I have an issue and I can't seem to get around it.

I have button that opens up a slider in the same page (move a section of the page right and reveal text underneath) but when you click on the button I want to point to the href to move the text-slider to the top of the page and also execute the slider function to activate.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="st-trigger-effects">
<button ng-click="edu_non_sports()" data-effect="st-effect-3" class="btn-   transparent sidebar-btn">
    <img src="images/non-sport-extra-murals.svg">
</button>
```

Its just a basic button that activated the slider, but it is set to a specific section on the page. So when when you click on the button, it opens the slider but you have to then scroll to see the section that was opened.

So I want to know, how can I get the button to:

1. Move to the section of the page I want to see on the screen, and then also
2. Execute the code that actually opens the slider to reveal the text

Comment: update your question to include some code

Comment: How we understood your problem from just explanation. post sample code here.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)